# Structure of images

Tags: graphics

I'm trying to insert figures in my code with:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=5cm,height=5cm]{1.png}
\includegraphics[width=5cm,height=5cm]{2.png}
\includegraphics[width=10cm,height=10cm]{3.png}
\caption{title...}
\label{fig:smooth_ent_1}
\end{figure}
```

But how can I give them these positions?
[image]

Comment: Image 3 doesn't have the sme width as the first two. Why  do you specify `width=0.32\textwidth` in all cases?

Comment: my code insert all the images on the same row. I've written it, but I want to change like in the figure that I posted in the question

Comment: But will image 3 be about twice as large as images 1 and 2?

Comment: Yes, I'd like this

Comment: what you realy need to specifi is the height

Comment: I've edited the code, with heigth. But how about positions like I've asked? SOrry if you can't understand my english very well, i don't speak it often

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{minipage}{.32\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{myfoto}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{myfoto}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.64\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{myfoto}
\end{minipage}
\caption{title...}
\label{fig:smooth_ent_1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```